# Code works when using Jquery 1.3.2 but fails with 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple HelloWorld webservice which returns Hello + Name and it works absolutely fine with Jquery 1.3.2 but returns undefined with 1.7.1
I am new to Jquery and have researched a lot but not able to fix.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
      url: "http://localhost:60105/WCFService3/Service.svc/HelloWorld",  
      data: '{"name":"John"}',  
      dataType: "json",  
      success: function(response) {  
      alert(response.HelloWorldResult);  
      },  
      error: function(message) {  
      alert("error has occured");  
      }  
    });  

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you checked it in any other version? http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/ Heres the changelog for 1.7

Comment: Not related to jQuery, but depending on your web server configuration, WCF might wrap its response in an object named `d`. Did you try `alert(response.d.HelloWorldResult);`?

Comment: What is in [`console.log(response)`](http://getfirebug.com/logging)?

Comment: @Frederic: let me try alert(response.d.HelloWorldResult);

Comment: It gives an alert saying "Error has occured". When I debug the javascript it goes down to the inspectPrefiltersOrTransports function which is returning undefined. hence the error

Comment: I realised that it works fine till 1.4.4 and fails for all versions after that.

Comment: **Quote OP**:  _"it works fine till 1.4.4 and fails for all versions after that"_  So look at the changelog for jQuery 1.5 to see what changed... http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning ajax / webservice stuff as well and this is what I've put together:

```
//Create an empty DTO (Data Transfer Object)
var DTO = {};

$(function () {
    // set Ajax default settings
    $.ajaxSetup({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "text", //do NOT set to json!!!
        converters: {
            "text json": function (jsonString) {
                var res = JSON.parseWithDate(jsonString);
                if (res && res.hasOwnProperty("d"))
                    res = res.d;
                return res;
            }
        },
        dataFilter: function (data) {
            var msg;
            if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' && typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function')
                msg = JSON.parse(data);
            else
                msg = eval('(' + data + ')');

            if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                return msg.d;
            else
                return msg;
        }
    });

    //Set the parameter of the DTO  
    DTO.name = "John";

    $.ajax({
        url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/WCFService3/Service.svc/HelloWorld",
        data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.HelloWorldResult);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err, desc) {
            alert(jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).Message);
        }
    });


});
```

for the JSON.stringify part, if your browser doesn't support it you will need to include the json2_min.js file available from:

http://www.json.org/js.html

For the site I'm currently working on, I simply add parameters to the DTO object where needed which will then be turned into JSON and passed to the service.

For the Ajax setup, that deals with the "d" field, which was introduced in .NET 3.5

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

was is your server returning? In the latest version jQuery relies on native browser json parsing, so that the response has to be valid json, and not smth like '{status:"off"}'.

Also, the "data" parameter may be an object, not just a string

Comment: That is probably a reason. Try replacing it with returning a json object.